# Running ride.py shows error "wxPython with ansi encoding is not supported"

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, robotframework

When executing a file called *ride.py*, I get the following error message:

> wxPython with ansi encoding is not supported You need to install
>   wxPython 2.8 toolkit with unicode support to run RIDE. See
>   http://wxpython.org for more information.

Configuration:

- My OS is CentOS6
- Python version is 2.7
- wxWidget version is 2.8.12
- Ride version is robotframework-ride-1.1
- robotframework version is 2.7.7

It looks that the ride doesn't support ansi mode.
But xw.platformINfo includes "ansi" as below.

```
>>> print wx.PlatformInfo
('__WXGTK__', 'wxGTK', 'ansi', 'gtk2', 'wx-assertions-off', 'SWIG-1.3.29')
```

But wxPython, which is source, is compiled on OS. So I don't know how to set "ansi" mode.
Compile steps are noted below:

```
   $../configure --prefix=/opt/wx/2.8 \
             --with-gtk \
             --with-gnomeprint \
             --with-opengl \
             --enable-debug \
             --enable-debug_gdb \
             --enable-geometry \
             --enable-graphics_ctx \
             --enable-sound --with-sdl \
             --enable-mediactrl \
             --enable-display \
             --with-libjpeg=builtin \
             --with-libpng=builtin \
             --with-libtiff=builtin \
             --with-zlib=builtin ; 
   $vi .make 
      (content of .make file)
      make $* \
           && make -C contrib/src/gizmos $* \
           && make -C contrib/src/stc $* 
   $.make
   $.make install 

   $cd wxPython
   $python setup.py build_ext --inplace --debug  WX_CONFIG=/opt/wx/2.8/bin/wx-config BUILD_GLCANVAS=0 
   $python setup.py install WX_CONFIG=/opt/wx/2.8/bin/wx-config
```

Thanks for your comments.

---

Can I change the value of the wx.PlatformInfo?????

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've installed the ANSI version of wxPython and from the [Installation Instructions](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-ride/wiki/InstallationInstructions) for robotframework-ride (their emphasis):

> RIDE's GUI is implemented using wxPython toolkit. Version 2.8.6 or
>   newer with **Unicode support** is required. The ANSI version is not
>   supported.

So you'll need to reinstall wxPython after it's been built with Unicode support. As per the [build guide](http://wxpython.org/BUILD-2.8.html), your config should include `--enable-unicode` and look something like this:

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/wx/2.8 \
             --with-gtk \
             --with-gnomeprint \
             --with-opengl \
             --enable-debug \
             --enable-debug_gdb \
             --enable-geometry \
             --enable-graphics_ctx \
             --enable-sound --with-sdl \
             --enable-mediactrl \
             --enable-display \
             --enable-unicode \
             --with-libjpeg=builtin \
             --with-libpng=builtin \
             --with-libtiff=builtin \
             --with-zlib=builtin \
```

Answer (score 0):

Add --enable-unicode to the configure command.

Answer (score 0):

Another point to be noted while using ride on linux(atleast RHEL and centos )is the python version. in my experience ride won't work with python 2.7. you'll have to use python 2.6.